# Is it possible to get user list with paging ,sorting IdentityUser Tables .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, api, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Is it possible to get user list with paging ,sorting IdentityUser Tables .Net Core. I try to make a panel that list, update, create user. I know i can get all of list of users with context but i dont know i can take records this userlist from context for paging sorting and another filter options. I can do it for other entity objects, I cannot find any example on it when googling and i would like to know what the best pratictise is that when i get user list in api? Could you explain please ?

```
public async Task<List<User>> GetUsersAsync()
{
    using (var context = new Context())
    {
        return await UserManager.Users.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your own pagination to your query.
See an example here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Taken from the link:

```
public static async Task<PaginatedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        var count = await source.CountAsync();
        var items = await source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
        return new PaginatedList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
    }
```

Comment: How could you filter them by their roles?